# Proof by contradiction: negation of conjunction

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Consider we have the following statement to prove: $P \implies Q \wedge R$.
For a proof by contradiction, we assume $P \wedge (\neg Q \lor \neg R)$.

How would one go about this? Typically to prove a statement of the form $(A \lor B) \implies C$, we show $A \implies C$ and then $B \implies C$. Do we break down such a proof by contradiction into such cases?

Mainly:

1. Does it suffice to reach separate contradictions by considering the cases $P \wedge \neg Q$ and $P \wedge \neg R$ separately?
2. Must one also consider the case when $(P \wedge \neg Q)$ and $(P \wedge \neg R)$ are both assumed to hold "simultaneously"?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you want to derive a contradiction (if any) from $P \wedge (\neg Q \lor \neg R)$, you have to consider the two cases forming the disjunction.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, yes that I know - I meant it 'loosely' i.e. in the context of the proof technique. Thank you for pointing it out - removed the sentence for clarity.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, so if I understood correctly, you first show contradiction of $P \wedge \neg Q$ independent of $P \wedge \neg R$, and then similarly for $P \wedge \neg R$ independent of $P \wedge \neg Q$.

Comment: See [Proof by cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination): if you show that (P∧¬Q)  implies a contra and that (P∧¬R) implies a contra, it is fine.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA, your last comment clarifies the matter for me. Please, how can I mark it as solved by you?

Comment: I have now posted an example that builds on top of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526121/proof-by-contradiction-structure-for-statement-of-the-form-p-implies-exists-x Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to derive a contradiction (if any) from $P ∧ (¬Q∨¬R)$, we have to consider the two cases forming the equivalent disjunction:

> $(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ ( P ∧ ¬R)$.

See [Proof by cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination): if we show that $(P∧¬Q)$ implies a contradiction and that $(P∧¬R)$ implies a contradiction, it is done.

Comment: You should have said *or*,  not *and*.

Comment: @BenW --- NO. Se the Wiki entry regarding Didjunction Elim linked above: if we have $P \to R$ **and** $ \to R$, we can conclude that $R$ follows from $P \lor Q$.