# Proof by contradiction structure for statement of the form $P \implies \exists x \in X: Q(x) \wedge R(x)$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

For a proof by contradiction, we suppose $P \wedge \forall x \in X: \neg Q(x) \lor \neg R(x)$.

Is the following proof outline sound?

We show that for a particular $a \in X$, chosen and specified,

1. Assume $P \wedge \neg Qa$ and reach (if any) a contra $A \wedge \neg A$,
2. Assume $P \wedge \neg Ra$ and reach (if any) a contra $A \wedge \neg A$

while noting that the contra in 1. and 2. have been achieved with the chosen $a \in X$.

The issue that I have is that I’m specifying a particular $a \in X$ a-priori, rather then for any $x \in X$. Is this enough since we have universal quantification?

How I’m understanding it, you’re assuming that some $A$ holds when the negation is true for all $x \in X$, however you have constructed one $a \in X$ for which we can conclude $\neg A$.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting - on mobile it does not show a preview.

Comment: No, it's not enough.  You need to let $a$ be arbitrary.  Also, you don't need to prove both (1) and (2).  Proving *either* (1) or (2) is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. How does universal quantification change the requirement of getting a contradiction in both cases? In reference to a question I asked yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523038/proof-by-contradiction-negation-of-conjunction

Comment: It doesn't.  $\vee$ means or : )

Comment: Yes, that I know. I’m just a bit confused since the other solution seems to state the contrary for proof by contradiction involving $\lor$ in the negation.

Comment: What "other solution"?

Comment: Sorry, I linked to the question I asked yesterday. Please find attached: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3523062/691545

Comment: I think you mean distributivity?

Comment: Oops, quite so.

Comment: I misunderstood your question and deleted my answer. Your statement is not true in general.

Comment: No problem, Dan :-) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Dan So then you mean my proof outline? I would have to choose an arbitrary $a \in X$?

Comment: You will need other assumptions to prove your statement. You have not stated, for example, that $X$ is non-empty, so you cannot construct $a \in X$.

Comment: Thanks. This is just an outline of an underlying proof for an assignment in graph theory. I know that the sets are non-empty. In reality I know what everything is. How can I better word my question? To clarify that it is an outline for a mathematical proof. The contra is reached using other definition etc accessible by virtue of the material.

Comment: So there is missing information after all. So I will undelete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Assume $P$
2. Assume $\forall x\in X: [\neg Q(x) \lor \neg R(x)]$
3. Obtain contradiction $A \land \neg A$
4. Conclude $\neg\forall x \in X: [\neg Q(x) \lor \neg R(x)]$ (discharging 2)
5. $\exists x\in X: [ Q(x) \land R(x)]$ (from 4)
6. Conclude $P \implies \exists x\in X: [ Q(x) \land R(x)]$ (discharging 1)

Comment: Thanks, Dan. My issue is (which perhaps I should have phrased better): do I show 3. for any x? Or does it suffice to construct at least 1 x that contradicts?

Comment: @XandruMifsud The proposition $A$ does not strictly require any reference to any elements of $X$.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. So in my current proof, I’m tacking it as follows: after having constructed some $a \in X$, I begin by assuming $P \wedge \neg Qa$. The contra I have reached is $Qa \wedge \neg Qa$. I then construct some $b \in X$, not necessarily the same as $a$, and from $P \wedge \neg Rb$ I get $Rb \wedge \neg Rb$. Two remarks: i. From your reply, I then take it that this is an INVALID proof due to the dependency of the contra in some $a, b \in X$. ii. In this case on choosing $a \in X$ for the contra $Qa \wedge \neg Qa$, does it matter if $Ra$ holds or not since we are doing proof by cases?

Comment: By proof, I mean mathematical proof: I know the set, and statements. But since there are many moving parts, I’m concerned on the proof technique.

Comment: @XandruMifsud Even we know that $X$ is non-empty, you would have to provide additional information to be able to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Yes I understand...suppose I provide that information to reach the contra, would the outline be valid? Thanks for you help and excuse my poor wording. I will update my question once I’m on my laptop.

Comment: @XandruMifsud You might then click the check mark in your left margin beside my answer.